# SQL Performance with Autocomplete

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to make an autocomplete textbox in a windows forms. My idea is to make a call to the  database in the TextChanged function, so I can get the autocomplete options to the user dynamically. I need to know if this affects in any way to the database performance. As  I know something similar is made with the autocomplete jquery controls in a web environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the database every time TextChanged is triggered is probably not a great idea...generally you should avoid frequent calls to the database, it's good practice.

I would suggest creating a list from the database at form initialization and using that list for the autocomplete options.

**EDIT:**

In the `TextChanged` event;

```
if (txtFilter.Text.Length >= 3)
{
    foreach (string s in AutoCompleteList)
    {
        if (s.Contains(s))
        {
            // add to list of Suggestions
        }
    }
}
```

You can then take the Suggestions list and display it in the AutoComplete.

Comment: I see your point. But what about the jquery autocomplete. Does it work that way?

Comment: I'm not sure that it does query a database...from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/; The datasource is a simple JavaScript array, provided to the widget using the source-option.

Comment: And waht about making the call after taping the first three letters?. Making the call and then, make a filter with the new characters with obtained data.